# How do i get a red webpage, i only get yellow (i`m a beginner)

Tags: php, html, if-statement

```
<?php // some of the php code is in dutch

$graden_celcius=0; // dutch for degrees celcius

$html = <<< OET

 Hoe warm is het nu? // dutch for " whats the temperature now?"

  <br />

  <form action="#" method="post">

   In graden celcius :

    <input type="text" name="dob" value="" />

    <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Tempr" />

  </form>

OET;

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    if($graden_celcius>=0&&$graden_celcius<=30)
         echo '<body style="background-color:yellow">';   
     else  
          echo '<body style="background-color:red">'; 
 } else {
    echo $html;
 }
?>
```

Comment: Set `$graden_celcius` to a value above 30?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, add this line

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$graden_celcius = $_POST['dob']; //This doesn't filter anything though, in case you are doing further processing.

if($graden_celcius>=0&&$graden_celcius<=30)
```

You've checked if you have the form sent by the existence of 'submit', but you haven't read the submitted value of the 'dob' POST variable also sent. You can see these variables and what they contain using the Chrome Devtools.

I'm not sure, do you have any other HTML above / below your php though?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get the value from the post variable. Do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['dob']))
        $graden_celcius = $_POST['dob'];
    if($graden_celcius>=0  &&  $graden_celcius<=30)
        echo '<body style="background-color:yellow">'; 
    else  
        echo '<body style="background-color:red">'; 
}
else
{
    echo $html;
}
```

Since you seem to be learning PHP, I'll show you that you could have done this code better, like this:

```
<?php // some of the php code is in dutch

 $graden_celcius=0; // dutch for degrees celcius

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if (isset($_POST['dob']))
            $graden_celcius = $_POST['dob'];

        if($graden_celcius>=0&&$graden_celcius<=30)
             echo '<body style="background-color:yellow">'; 
        else  
              echo '<body style="background-color:red">'; 
    }
 else
    { ?>
         Hoe warm is het nu? // dutch for " whats the temperature now?"

          <br />

          <form action="#" method="post">

           In graden celcius :

            <input type="text" name="dob" value="" />

            <br />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Tempr" />

          </form>

        <?php 
     }

?>
```

You can open as many PHP tags as you want in your page. That way you can switch from PHP to HTML easily, and the PHP has control over the HTML output as well.

Comment: Thank you @Phiter Fernandes

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't supply a number/variable for $graden_celcius. Change your dob input like...

```
<input type="text" name="graden_celcius" value="" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Tempr" />
```

THEN check the value....

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $graden_celcius = $_POST['graden_celcius'];
  if($graden_celcius>=0&&$graden_celcius<=30)
```